How to solve an inequality that contains standard deviation in python?
I have the past 19 days of stock price stored in the pd.dataframe and I am trying to find out the price P that is smaller than (mean - 2.5*standard deviation), where mean and standard deviation are calculated based on P and the past 19 days prices.
The inequality will be something like below:
P < mean - 2.5*standard deviation
I am assuming using solve in SymPy, but I got the error 'loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Add which has no callable sqrt method' when calling np.std().
This is the demo code:
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
solve(x-np.mean([1,2,3,x])-np.std([1,2,3,x]), x)

Error message:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'Add' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [71], in <cell line: 4>()
      2 from sympy import Symbol
      3 x = Symbol('x')
----> 4 solve(x-np.mean([1,2,3,x])-np.std([1,2,3,x]), x)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:3645, in std(a, axis, dtype, out, ddof, keepdims, where)
   3642     else:
   3643         return std(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof, **kwargs)
-> 3645 return _methods._std(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof,
   3646                      **kwargs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:214, in _std(a, axis, dtype, out, ddof, keepdims, where)
    212     ret = ret.dtype.type(um.sqrt(ret))
    213 else:
--> 214     ret = um.sqrt(ret)
    216 return ret

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Add which has no callable sqrt method

Or maybe are there any other better methods?

Which method of solving inequalities in SciPy are you using? Can you provide code?

It looks like you're using sympy, rather than SciPy. If so, I would suggest changing the tags on your question. They affect which kinds of experts see your question.

You can't mix sympy with script and numpy. They don't work together. Putting x, a sympy symbol, in a numpy array isn't possible.

I advise writing the equations (mean and standard deviation) yourself using just sympy and then solving it from there.

There are pure-python routines for mean and stddev here. With them (and using sqrt(x) instead of x**.5) you can generate your equation to solve:
>>> v=[1,2,3,x]; solve(x-mean(v)-stddev(v))
[2*sqrt(3)/3 + 2]
>>> _[0].n()
3.15470053837925

